# Uvicorn server timeout

Tags: python, rest, server, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to configure my server to have a request timeout but I can't find any information about it. I saw `uvicorn` has a property called `keep_alive_timeout` which defaults to 5 seconds. But that also doesn't seem to work.

For example:

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/test')
def test_endpoint():
    sleep(10)
```

I would expect the request to disconnect and have a timeout after 5 seconds but it persists and returns 200.

Anyone have any idea how to set it?

Comment: keep-alive tells the server how long to keep a connection open to a dormant client, not the other way around.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the server to stop the processing for a certain request because its been handling it for too long? for example what happens if it takes an hour for my server to process a request? would it just go on the entire time?

Comment: the client will timeout if it doesn't hear back, I want to say after 30 seconds, although that could be wrong.

Comment: Doesn't look like uvicorn has that functionality, probably because it's expected that you run it behind e.g. an nginx reverse proxy (https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-request-timeout-nginx/).

Comment: Even if the client times out, the server will still keep processing the request no? it wouldn't stop in the middle. I'm trying to understand how I could tell my server to stop processing a certain request if X seconds pass. Having the client disconnect doesn't achieve that if im not mistaken

Comment: Im actually running behind Nginx which have a timeout, but then again, my process remains alive in the server even when nginx raises this timeout.
Which then leaves the server running a request which no one listens to

Comment: You could try the middleware implemented [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1752#issuecomment-682579845). I haven't tried it myself, but it looks promising. This will actually cancel the running task.